# uint8_t* expected a ;

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

VS10 is underlining uint8_t, saying that it expected a semi-colon.

Here's my code snippet:-

```
uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)image.data; //this line shows the error (expected a ;)
```

Yet, when I use it lower down my code, no errors are attached to it:-

```
typedef Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel; //this line is error free
```

Comment: with regards to including stdint.h, yes I did!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non Static Member Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763315/non-static-member-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget a `;` on a previous `class` or `struct` declaration?  If so, then it's interpreting `uint8_t` as a variable name that is an instance of that `struct` or `class`.

For example, if you did this:

```
class clown
{
    // yadda
    // yadda
    ... 
} // notice no semicolon here

uint8_t *pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)image.data;
```

The compiler effectively sees:

```
class clown
{
    // yadda
    // yadda
    ... 
} uint8_t *pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)image.data;
```

and naturally wants a semicolon after `uint8_t`, so it looks more like this:

```
class clown
{
    // yadda
    // yadda
    ... 
} uint8_t; // which would declare an instance of class clown named uint8_t
```

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid! Thank you for your help, I didn't include a semi colon on the line above! I'll mark your answer as correct! Apparently, I can only do that in 7 mins...So thanks again anyway!

Comment: Glad to help.  Far smarter people than I have made this mistake.  I think we all learn this one scraping our knees on it directly.