# Non Static Member Reference

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I've got an error in my code below:-

```
int main() {

cv::Mat image = imread("file.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)image.data;
int cn = image.channels();
 for(int i = 0; i < image.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < image.cols; j += cn)
    {
        typedef Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;
        bgrPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 0]; // B
        bgrPixel.val[1] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 1]; // G
        bgrPixel.val[2] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 2]; // R

    // do somethin
    }
}
}
```

VS10 underlines val[0] and says a non-static member reference must be relative to a specific object. But it is - it's relative to bgrPixel, isn't it?

Comment: You'll probably need to show at least a little more context for anybody to say much meaningful about it.

Comment: If the compiler doesn't think so, who are we to disagree? Can you show more code?

Comment: I'll add more code now...one second

Comment: Ok, just remove the word `typedef` and see what happens.

Comment: @RogerRowland GENIUS! Thank you! Why did that happen?

Comment: You're welcome - the `typedef` just introduced an alias for that type, it didn't declare a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Longer explanation:

The following line:

```
typedef Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;
```

Declares an alias - `brgPixel` - that can be used in place of `Scalar_<uint8_t>` - it really just saves typing and makes the code a little cleaner and easier to read. Also - in other situations - it allows you to change that type by amending the `typedef` rather than doing a find/replace for the variable type iteself.

What it doesn't do is declare any variable *of* that type.

So either you can remove the `typedef` and just declare a variable:

```
Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;
bgrPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 0];
```

Or, you can use the `typedef` as the variable type:

```
typedef Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;
bgrPixel pPixel;
pPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*image.cols*cn + j*cn + 0];
```